# Convex hull of Minkowski sums

Tags: geometry

I was reading the wikipedia article about [Minkowski addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition). There's a proposition there:

> For all subsets S1 and S2 of a real vector-space, the convex hull of
>   their Minkowski sum is the Minkowski sum of their convex hulls
>   Conv(S1 + S2) = Conv(S1) + Conv(S2)

Where + is the Minkowski addition.
But for a simple example it doesn't hold.

Assume $A = \{(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)\}$ and $B=\{(3, 0), (4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1)\}$. Then we have $A + B = \{(3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2)\}$.

Both $A$ and $B$ are convex, thus they're equal to their convex hull, but $A + B$ is clearly not convex (because of vector (4, 1)).

Is this proposition has some conditions, or am I missing something in Minkowski addition here?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ aren't convex at all!

Comment: $A+B$ is not convex because it includes $(4,1)$? I think you have the wrong idea of what "convex" means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First picture contains $A$ and $B$ (black dots $\bullet$) and their convex hulls (blue and red). The second diagram depicts Minkowski sum of $A$ and $B$, the convex hull of Minkowski (magenta) and Minkowski sum of convex hulls of $A$ and $B$ (also magenta). Observe that $A \neq \mathrm{ConvexHull}(A)$, in other words, $A$ is not convex and neither is $B$, therefore $A+B$ does not need to be convex.
On the other hand, indeed $\mathrm{ConvexHull}(A) + \mathrm{ConvexHull}(B) = \mathrm{ConvexHull}(A + B)$.

[image: minkowski]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. I think I misunderstood the Convex Hull. I thought ConvexHull(A) is a subset of A, which is set of vertices of a Convex polygon covering all points in A.